# Use and (&) in queryset only when the parameters extists Django

Tags: django

I don't know if there's a quick way to do this, but what I want to do is a search according to six parameters, where 5 of them come from Select Inputs, and the other one from an Input text, the search needs to be more specific when more options are selected.

Is there a way to do this with lookups? Or I need to make an `if` for every combination of parameters? If I have to write all the if's, what is the more efficient way? Because if I'll have to do `2^6` `if` statements to cover all the combinations, that will be a little bit slow. Consider that the parameters doesn't have an specific order, so any combination is possible.

I was thinking in `Q objects` but I don't know if they work for that, I have only used them for OR satements, I know that they can be used for `and` statements too, but I don't know if they are different than using `comma`. Probably something like this:

```
result = Product.objects.filter(Q(field1=param1)&Q(field2=param2)&Q(field3=param3)&Q(field4=param4)&Q(field5=param5)&Q(field6=param6))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use `Q` and `&`. Every filter operation does `and` with previous. So You will have the same number of `if` operations as parameters.

```
q = Product.objects.all()
if param1 != None:
    q = q.filter(field1=param1)
if param2 != None:
    q = q.filter(field2=param2)
#and so on
```

It is equivalent to your code but with `if`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you probably have access to a form's `cleaned_data` and you're looking to do something like an "advanced search." In that case, given that all of the form fields are relevant to the search, you could do something like

`result = Product.objects.filter(**form.cleaned_data)`

since you want to only include fields that are specified you can then add a filtering statement to ensure you're only looking at the relevant fields. Unfortunately, that depends a lot on how your form looks. If your form's non-empty values are all truthy, you could do something like

`result = Product.objects.filter(**{k: v for k, v in form.cleaned_data.items() if v})`

If on the other hand, you only want to apply filters where the fields have changed from what they populated the form with, you might be well served by

`result = Product.objects.filter(**{k: v for k, v in form.cleaned_data.items() if form.changed_data})`

Unfortunately, if you have a checkbox named `turtle_safe`, you'll need to record whether someone's indicated that they want results that are safe for turtles or results that are not safe for turtles. Both of the follow up approaches I've suggested would not apply a filter for "not safe for turtles" and would instead filter for "no preference for turtle safety" (assuming the default is False in the option with `changed_data`).

If that isn't sufficient, you may be able to avoid posting fields that the user hasn't deliberately selected by disabling / enabling the fields with javascript until the user adds them for their search.

If you end up with that, you may want to set the default values to `None` and use the second check (so long as `None` isn't a valid option!).

Comment: That's really good, but I forgot to say that I'm using AJAX for the requests, so I have "plain" variables, not forms. But this looks interesting, I'm going to try it in other searches where I submit the entire form.

Comment: FYI form data can work just fine with AJAX data. Just send it to the same view and the form will pick it up. You'll probably want a json response though.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8244082/3208419

Comment: Oh, that's why formData() exists haha, that's why I think DJango is amazing, it automates a lot of programming. With formData() I send the data, and in DJango just receive it like:    myform=theform(request.POST), just like a normal submit right?

Comment: Exactly! The javascript is a little tricky because those extra parameters (processData and contentType) are required.